# how to set regular expressions in .bat file?

Tags: regex, batch-file, replace

I have this string in my `httpd.conf` file:

```
Listen 12.0.0.0:80
```

and I want to replace the ip address and the semi-colon with `=`.

My batch command is:

```
type C:\h\httpd.conf |repl "Listen (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):" "Listen =" >C:\h\h.conf
```

The result is `Listen =80`

But if there are several white-characters between `Listen` and the ip address, how to write the regular expression?

Example:

```
Listen                                                                           

        12.0.0.0:80
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear in my opinion. Do you mean that you would like to create a batch file which listens on a dynamic ip + port?

Comment: Listen and ip address between white space how to find match expresstion ?? Listen(whitespace)12.0.0.0:80 ,one or two white space

Comment: What do you want to achieve with your code?

Comment: Listen     (whitespace)     12.0.0.0:80 {white space not working http://stackoverflow.com/  so i put whitespace listen and 12.0.0.0:80}

Comment: Oh, language barriers.

Comment: i  replaced (Listen 12.0.0.0:80 to Listen = 80) it is working ,but Listen and 12.0.0.0:80 have more white space that code not working.

Comment: I am sorry I just don't get anything of what you are saying :p

Comment: regular expression symbol for white spaces ,one or more white spaces

Comment: `\s` is the unix regex symbol for white space including space, tab, form feed, etc., but not newline. See http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/regular_expressions.html for full list.

Comment: i got answer                                                               type C:\h\httpd.conf |repl "# directive." "[love]"|repl "Listen +\s(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):" "Listen=" >C:\h\h.conf

Comment: type C:\h\httpd.conf |repl "# directive." "[love]"|repl "Listen +\s(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):" "Listen=" >C:\h\h.conf  this is answer  thanks for helping repl is bat file link http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

Comment: is there any possible replace Listen = 127.0.0.1:8080 to Listen =127.0.0.1

Comment: like find different ip address  replace Listen =127.0.0.1:8080  to  Listen =127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand this correctly.

You are trying to replace an ip address and port with something and want whitespaces as begin and end marker.

As I am not sure what exactly you want I will simply explain a few basic rules:

```
\d{1,3}
```

This is the same as saying:  1 - 3 digits.
Example would be: 123 or 789 or 999

The **.** in your regular expression will match anything!  You should escape it.

This:
    \d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}
will match 1-3 digits, followed by anything, followed by 1-3 digits...
Examples:
  999a888b777c666 but of course also IP addresses:  127.0.0.1

The **(** and **)** don't do anything in your example.  You could probably remove them.

If you want to match a space character you can simply write it.

```
"Listen (\d{1,3}.   \d{1,3}.   \d{1,3}.   \d{1,3})"
```

will only match IP addresses with spaces:

```
127.   0.   0.   1
```

If you want to make them optional add a ***** afterwards:

```
"Listen  *(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})"
```

Notice the « *» after the space after "Listen "  it allows additional spaces.
Example:

```
Listen       127.0.0.1
```

If you want to match the ip address with the port

```
"Listen  *(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):\d{1,5}"
```

If you want to print a matched value again this is usually \1 (\2,...)

```
type C:\h\httpd.conf |repl "Listen (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5})" "Listen =" >C:\h\h.conf
```

will replace **Listen 127.0.0.1:8080** with **Listen =**

```
type C:\h\httpd.conf |repl "Listen (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5})" "Listen = \1" >C:\h\h.conf
```

will (**probably**) replace **Listen 127.0.0.1:8080** with **Listen = 127.0.0.1**

Hope that helps.